# Problem running VLC on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: vlc, 14.10

There's no doubt a simple explanation for this, but since updating to Ubuntu 14.10 I've been having a problem with VLC 2.2.0.

It's nothing major but on all video whether from DVD or from the hard disk I'm getting a thin green line down the right hand side of the picture. It does not go away in full screen and seems to occur on all the video I have attempted to watch.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VLC a number of times with no change. This does not occur on other media players such as SMPlayer.

If anyone could help me solve this, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks,

Ben